# How to count the number of matches in two files of different structures in Perl

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, hashtable

Sorry if it is too simple question. But my mind have gotten stuck when it comes to one problem in my code below. The question will be followed.

```
1. open(my $go_file, "<", "gene_associations_go_human.txt") or die "Can't open the file!"; 
2. open(my $selected_genes, "<", "my_selected_genes.txt") or die "Can't open the file!";
3. open(my $output, ">", "output_go_file.txt") or die "Can't open the file!";

4. my %go_hash; 
5. chomp(my @sel_genes=<$selected_genes>);

6. while(<$go_file>){

7.        chomp($_);
8.        my @go_line=split("\t", $_);

9.        $go_hash{$go_line[4]}=[] unless exists $go_hash{$go_line[4]}; 
10.       push @{$go_hash{$go_line[4]}}, $go_line[2];
11. }

12. foreach my $go_term (sort keys %go_hash){

13.      my @genes=@{$go_hash{$go_term}};
14.      @genes= uniq(@genes);

15.      my $count=0;
16.      foreach my $element(@genes){
17.            my $score=grep{$element eq $_} @sel_genes;
18.            $count++ if($score>0);
19       }

21.      @genes=sort(@genes);
22.      push(@genes, ($#genes+1, $count));

23.      print $output($go_term."\t".join("\t",@genes)), "\n";

24. }
25. close($go_file);
26. close($selected_genes);
27. close($output);
```

> > > Edit: Example of Input and Output files

```
**$go_file:**
UniProtKB   A0A183  LCE6A   NA  GO:0031424
UniProtKB   A0A5B9  TRBC2   NA  GO:0016021
UniProtKB   A0AUZ9  KANSL1L NA  GO:0000123
UniProtKB   A0AV02  SLC12A8 NA  GO:0006813
UniProtKB   A0AV02  SLC12A8 NA  GO:0015293
UniProtKB   A0AV02  SLC12A8 NA  GO:0016021


**$selected_genes:**
DOLPP1
SPIC1
KANSL1L
SLC12A8
TRAF1
CDF7

**$output should be like this:**
GO:0000123  KANSL1L 1   1   
GO:0006813  SLC12A8 1   1   
GO:0031424  LCE6A   1   0   
GO:0015293  SLC12A8 1   1   
GO:0016021  SLC12A8 TRBC2   2   1
```

I am making `%go_hash` (based on `$go_file`) which keeps arrays of genes (`3rd column` of the file) based on associated `$go_terms` (`5th column` of the file), so lengths of arrays in the `%go_hash` can be different. I have another file, `$selected_genes`, which has only one column of more than 5000 unique genes. I should count number of genes in each array of `%go_hash` and find the number of genes of each array that exists in `$selected_genes` list too (in case no overlapping, `0` should be there). Then add these two numbers to the end of corresponding array in the hash and make new `$output` file. Everything is fine in the final result when it is printed to this output file except one thinkg. The counter variable `$count`, number of genes of each array overlapping with `$selected_genes`, is resulting in `0` all the time. (Actually there are many overlappings, so it should not be `0` all the time). I tried many ways but no change, especially with the lines of the code between 15th and 19th. Maybe the problem is in other parts of the code.

Where am I doing mistake? Can someone correct me? In advance, thank you for any comment/help.

Comment: Your code *looks* alright, although inefficient. Could you post a few lines of example input, and the expected output for that input? It is difficult for me to understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @amon Edit is done. I have just given small part of the files. Actually they are large. Thanks.

Comment: I looked into it, but you do get the expected output, although in a slightly different order. All the counts are alright. Can you verify this?

Comment: Yes here in an example counts are alright because I just posted expected rough output (yeah, ordering can be different) not the actual one that I took. The last column of the number of overlapping genes is still 0 for all the raws in my actual result.

Comment: Then *something* is different with the actual input – the question is *what*. Can you please post input that exhibits your problem?

Comment: check line breaks of your input file, is it same as $/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open my $go_file, "gene_associations_go_human.txt" or die "Can't open the file!"; 
open my $selected_genes, "my_selected_genes.txt" or die "Can't open the file!";

my %sel_genes = map { chomp; $_ => 1 } <$selected_genes>;

my %result; 
while(<$go_file>){
  chomp;
  my @r = split /\t/;

  $result{$r[4]} = { count1=>0, count2=>0, data=>{}} if not defined $result{$r[4]};
  $result{$r[4]}->{count1}++;

  $result{$r[4]}->{data}->{$r[2]} = defined $sel_genes{$r[2]} ? 1 : 0; 
  $result{$r[4]}->{count2}++ if defined $sel_genes{$r[2]}; 
}

for my $r (keys %result) {
  print $r . "\t" . join("\t", keys %{$result{$r}->{data}}) . "\t" . $result{$r}->{count1} . "\t" . $result{$r}->{count2} . "\n";
}
```